# How to find Parent Control when the Nested Control is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[A screenshot of the user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnwal.jpg)

I am using WinForm. I am trying to get the name of the parent control to appear. Example - in the 1st UC on the left, when I click on any Date (the checkbox), it must output 'Durban'. If I click on any Date from the 2nd UC on the right, it must output 'Maputo' using a MessageBox or something.

I am new to to this and I have tried every way possible or at least of what I know.

note ~ both UC are made by me. the main control is the one that shows city name and month selection, the nested control is the date icon (which contains the date and checkbox). so when i click on the date icon, it must show which parent control it belongs to, as mentioned above, because the user can select 7 different cities and so we have to keep track of which date was selected for which city.

edit -
this is what I tried, along with a few other Controls.OtherMethods to see if something might work. I have also attached a response that I get once I click the Date Icon

```
private void DateIconPanel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This date belongs to - " + DateCheckBox.Controls.Owner);

    }
```

[This is the response I get back after clicking the Date Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq305.jpg)

Comment: show us your code (what do you already tried to do?)

Comment: For the Name: `((Control)sender).Parent.Name`  ? For Text etc the respective property..

Comment: @vasily.sib I have edited and added the code that I tried and the result I got back from the code.

Comment: You can also utilize [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) to ease identification of controls.

Comment: So, that thing with scrollbar is `DateIconPanel`. Each line of which is `DateIcon`. Together with city name (like `Durban`) and a combobox - it is a your `UC`. Then what is `DateCheckBox`? And also, I guess `DateCheckBox.Controls.Owner == DateCheckBox`?

Comment: @TaW I tried this. Once the 'DateIon' UC is clicked, the MessageBox says 'The date belongs to - DateIcon'. Instead, it should say 'The date belongs to - DateGridView'. 'DateGridView' is basically the Parent Control UC that I created. Each city has it own 'DateGridView'. This 'DateGridView' basically show all 'DateIcon' UCs. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @vasily.sib you have checkout the attached images first. Each city gets its own CDG.cs and each CDG will contain all DI.cs as you can see in the attached images. So once the user clicks on a DateIcon UC, the name of relevant CDG.cs must show as each DateIcon belongs to certain City. link https://imgur.com/a/QmdS50e

Comment: Well, if you always want one level further out you can use Parent.Parent. If you don't know the level you can try from parent to parent.parent etc until you find a control of the right type.

Comment: @TaW it's working. The double Parent.Parent. It gives me the name of the Parent control which called 'CustomDateGrid'. So, now every 'CustomDateGrid' contains 30/31 DateIcon UC. On clicking the DateIcon I am getting back 'The date belongs to - CustomDateGrid', which is correct, but it is not showing the 'Name' or 'Title' of that particular CDG, like 1st CDG is Durban, 2nd CDG is Maputo and so on. Also, I have attached detailed images in the comment above.

Comment: A recursive function to find a parent of a type (here tabpage): `TabPage findPage(Control clicked)
{
    if (clicked.Parent == null) return null;
    if (clicked.GetType() == typeof( TabPage)) return (TabPage)clicked;
    return findPage(clicked.Parent);
}`- To find details you need to cast to the UC type and then drill into its controls. If you can't access them make them `Modifier internal` !

Comment: @TaW Thanks. Took some research but finally achieved it.